Some problem related to right-ordered group
In a paper Small doubling in ordered groups: generators and structure it is proven in Lemma 4 page no. 598 that:
Let $G$ be an ordered group. Let $S$ be a finite subset of $G$ with at least two elements. Let either $ m=$ max $S$ or $m=$ min $S$ and $T= S\setminus\{m\}.$ Then either $\langle S\rangle$ is a 2-generated abelian group, or $|T^2|\leq |S^2|-3. $
I am trying to look at this problem in the right-ordered groups. There are a few examples where we see this lemma does not hold for the right-ordered group. But if we take a set with identity element then  I stated it as follows.
Let $S$ be a finite subset of a right-ordered group containing identity with at least two elements. Let  $m$ = max $S$  and $A=S\setminus\{m\},$ and Then either $\langle S\rangle$ is an abelian  group, or $|A^2|\leq |S^2|-3.$
I tried to prove it like this
Let $S=\{e,x_2,\ldots, x_k\}$ and $A=\{e, x_2,\ldots, x_{k-1}\}.$
Suppose $x_ix_j$ be the maximum element of $A^2$ then $x_ix_j<x_kx_j$ therefore $x_kx_j\notin A^2.$
Consider $x_jx_k,$ if $x_kx_j= x_jx_k\implies x_kx_j<x_k^2.$
If $x_kx_j\neq x_jx_k,$ How to show that $x_jx_k\notin A^2$?
So here clearly one element we can see which is not in $A^2,$ how to show two more elements which are not in $A^2$?
I have posted this question on mathoverflow also.
Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thank you!
